# Home bed missing or obstructed when it's not

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I placed my bed in my house and slept there a couple times. I didn't break it. Then I died for the first time, and it said that my bed was missing or obstructed.

Then I spawned at the world's original spawn point. I searched for hours and finally found my house. I checked that my bed was there and it was.

I died some more times and still the same thing happened... I now know the way to my home, but I can't live and every time run for a long time to get home.

Please help.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Arqade! Can you post a screenshot of the room with your bed in it? It is possibly obstructed, which prevents you from spawning there.

Answer (score 3):

Are there blocks around the [bed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed)? The bed checks for an area all around the bed, looking for a space where a player can stand. Make sure that at least one block around the bed is able to be stood on.

(This means that beds indented into the floor are not spawnable, even with slabs around it)